# pyqtgraph, plotting time series

Tags: python, datetime, plot, pyqtgraph

I'am trying to plot time serie with pyqtgraph. I've read  [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyqtgraph/pSIn0xNGodA/VsM9-3NJDZAJ), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151612/pyqtgraph-how-to-plot-time-series-date-and-time-on-the-x-axis) and [this](https://gist.github.com/friendzis/4e98ebe2cf29c0c2c232). But i'am not sure how to correctly use it.

My plot is a plot widget, and i use it this way:

```
graph.plot(aerosol_data, pen=pg.mkPen(color=colors[count], width=1, style=QtCore.Qt.SolidLine), axisItems={'bottom': TimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')})
```

where TimeAxisItem is defined like this:

```
class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        # PySide's QTime() initialiser fails miserably and dismisses args/kwargs
        return [useful_values_dict['useful_data']['data']['ISO_dates']]
```

where ISO_dates is a list of date and time in ISO format

I've also tried this:

```
graph.plotItem.plot(aerosol_data, pen=pg.mkPen(color=colors[count], width=1, style=QtCore.Qt.SolidLine), axisItems={'bottom': TimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')})
```

but with no effects (axis strings are stil numbers).

Then i tried to use the DateTimeAxis.py, this way:

```
date_axis = pg.DateAxisItem('bottom', pen=None, linkView=None, parent=None, maxTickLength=-1, showValues=True)
date_axis.tickStrings(useful_values_dict['useful_data']['data']['timestamp_dates'],1, 1)
```

but i get an error:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\DateAxisItem.py", line 161, in tickStrings
format_strings.append(x.strftime(tick_spec.format))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally solved my problem, it was quite easy.

I just needed to initialize my plot widget that way:

```
    date_axis = pg.graphicsItems.DateAxisItem.DateAxisItem(orientation = 'bottom')
    self.graph = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems = {'bottom': date_axis})
```

and plot my data that way:

```
    graph.plot(x = useful_values_dict['useful_data']['data']['timestamp_dates'],
               y = useful_values_dict['useful_data']['data'][raw_header],
               pen=pg.mkPen(color=colors[count],width=1,style=QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
```

with x data as an array of timestamp.

Thanks !

Comment: I wish i could but i don't remember neither my password nor my e-mail for the account which  i asked the question with.