# Show string values on x-axis in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I want to display string values for ticks on x-axis in `pyqtgraph`. Right now I am unable to figure out how to do that.

Ex:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, ,5, 6]
pg.plot(x, y)
```

When I try to pass the string array to the *`x`* variable it tries converting that to float and breaks the GUI with the error message.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Usually in pyqtgraph when dealing with custom axis strings people subclass [AxisItem](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/axisitem.html) and override [tickStrings](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/axisitem.html#pyqtgraph.AxisItem.tickStrings) with the strings they want displayed.

See e.g. [pyqtgraph : how to plot time series (date and time on the x axis)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151612/pyqtgraph-how-to-plot-time-series-date-and-time-on-the-x-axis)

Pyqtgraphs axisitem also has a built in [setTicks](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/axisitem.html?highlight=setticks#pyqtgraph.AxisItem.setTicks) that allows you to specify the ticks that are going to be displayed, this could be done for a simple problem like this instead of subclassing the AxisItem.

---

Plotting with custom string on x-axis could be done like this.

- Create a **dict with x-values together with the strings** to be displayed on the axis.

`xdict = {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d', 4:'e', 5:'f'}`

or by using

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
xdict = dict(enumerate(x))
```

- Use **setTicks in an AxisItem** or
  **Subclass AxisItem** and in tickStrings find the string corresponding to the value.

### 1. Using a standard pyqtgraph AxisItem and setTicks

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
    import pyqtgraph as pg

    x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    xdict = dict(enumerate(x))

    win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
    stringaxis = pg.AxisItem(orientation='bottom')
    stringaxis.setTicks([xdict.items()])
    plot = win.addPlot(axisItems={'bottom': stringaxis})
    curve = plot.plot(list(xdict.keys()),y)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        if sys.flags.interactive != 1 or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
            pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```

### 2. Implementation by subclassing AxisItem

This is a more generic method which can be easily changed to all kinds of fun things e.g. converting a unix timestamp to a date.

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
    import pyqtgraph as pg
    import numpy as np

    class MyStringAxis(pg.AxisItem):
        def __init__(self, xdict, *args, **kwargs):
            pg.AxisItem.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.x_values = np.asarray(xdict.keys())
            self.x_strings = xdict.values()

        def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
            strings = []
            for v in values:
                # vs is the original tick value
                vs = v * scale
                # if we have vs in our values, show the string
                # otherwise show nothing
                if vs in self.x_values:
                    # Find the string with x_values closest to vs
                    vstr = self.x_strings[np.abs(self.x_values-vs).argmin()]
                else:
                    vstr = ""
                strings.append(vstr)
            return strings

    x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    xdict = dict(enumerate(x))

    win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
    stringaxis = MyStringAxis(xdict, orientation='bottom')
    plot = win.addPlot(axisItems={'bottom': stringaxis})
    curve = plot.plot(list(xdict.keys()),y)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        if sys.flags.interactive != 1 or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
            pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```

Screenshot from example:
[image: Screenshot from example]

Comment: Good job, As a better way to create the `xdict` you can use `enumerate` : `xdict = dict(enumerate(x))`

Comment: You could also save yourself a lot of fiddly typing by using `x = 'abcdef'` instead of `x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`

Comment: How to show only the first and last ticks in the plot (`'a'` and `'f'`) and whenever you zoom-in, you can see others `['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`?

Answer (score 12):

I find it easiest to prepare a list of indices and a list of your strings and then `zip` them together:

```
ticks = [list(zip(range(5), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')))]
```

You can get an existing AxisItem of a PlotWidget like so:

```
pw = pg.PlotWidget()
xax = pw.getAxis('bottom')
```

And finally set the ticks of the axis like so:

```
xax.setTicks(ticks)
```

As far as I can tell, PlotWidgets automatically include 'bottom' and 'left' AxisItems, but you can create and add others if you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to accomplish the same task but was getting deprecated errors on 'PyQt5'. I barely changed luddek's answer but here it goes:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui

xdict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f'}
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
windows = pg.plot(x, y)
stringaxis = pg.AxisItem(orientation='bottom')
stringaxis.setTicks([xdict.items()])
windows.setAxisItems(axisItems = {'bottom': stringaxis})
QtWidgets.QApplication.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by modifying the `AxisItem.py` in `pyqtgrqph`.

For this, you need to add a "look-up list" in this class. I call it `self.LookUPticks`. The standard value I defined to be None. Find the line:

```
for j in range(len(strings)):
```

and past the following code after the line:

```
if self.LookUPticks == None:
   vstr = strings[j]
else:
    try:
        vstr = self.LookUPticks[int(strings[j])]
    except:
        vstr = ''
```

Works like a charm!