# Pyqtgraph string in x tick

Tags: python-3.5, pyqtgraph

So I have been playing with pyqtgraph and I came to a problem where I needed to add strings as x axis tick label (instead of default float). So I looked around and found [Show string values on x-axis in pyqtgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775468/show-string-values-on-x-axis-in-pyqtgraph)

The solution kind of does what I need to do (the first solution on the page, the second one will cause problems because I am on python 3.5). So I tried to modified the first solution, but it did not work.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg

x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
xdict = dict(enumerate(x))

win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
stringaxis = pg.AxisItem(orientation='bottom')
stringaxis.setTicks([xdict.items()])
plot = win.addPlot(axisItems={'bottom': stringaxis})
curve = plot.plot(xdict.keys(),y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if sys.flags.interactive != 1 or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```

The error I am getting is TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing on line

```
curve = plot.plot(xdict.keys(),y)
```

I tried turning it into a list, by doing it as follows:

```
curve = plot.plot(list(sdict.keys(),y))
```

but this made the output has a small problem[image: plot window with problem]

The problem is that there is another axis added to the top left of the plot. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was not sure if I could answer my own question so I looked it up and found https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. So here is the answer.

Go to pyqtgraph google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/pyqtgraph/string|sort:relevance/pyqtgraph/pSIn0xNGodA/79pR3dUBLAAJ and look for a question from Upol Ryskulova. He is asking the exact same question. The responses to that comment confirm that it is a bug in pyqtgraph. It has been fixed but the fix has not yet propagated to my anaconda distribution. So what I need to do is wait for some time and that bug will go away. The fix is also discussed in the group, and there is nothing wrong with he code.