# How to add string axis in pyqtgraph PlotWidget

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am trying to add an x-axis with strings ((2,3,5,1),(11:30pm,12:00am,12:30am,1:00am)). I have seen an example that was done using pytgraph.GraphicsWindow() by addPlot(axisItems) [Show string values on x-axis in pyqtgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775468/show-string-values-on-x-axis-in-pyqtgraph) , but there is no addPlot for PlotWidget() to add a x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

`GraphicsWindows` inherits from `GraphicsLayout` and its [`addPlot`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/graphicslayout.html#pyqtgraph.GraphicsLayout.addPlot) method creates a `PlotItem` and then passes all its parameters to the `PlotItem` constructor.

The `PlotWidget` class wraps a single `PlotItem` and the `PlotWidget` constructor also passes its parameters to the `PlotItem` constructor.

Therefore you should just be able to pass the `axisItems` parameter to the `PlotWidget` constructor. Something like:

```
myPlotWidget = PlotWidget(axisItems={'bottom': stringaxis})
```

Comment: Thanks titusjan, but if i pass stringaxis when initializing the PlotWidget, how do I update the stringaxis for new plot?

Comment: I have found a way to add string axis by using setTicks - 

myPlotWidget = PlotWidget()
myPlotWidget.plot((1,2,3,4),(2,3,5,1))
myPlotWidget.getAxis('bottom').setTicks([[(1,"11:30pm"),(2,"12:00am"),(3,"12:30am"),(4,1:00am)]])