# How to return getXPos() values of pg.InfiniteLine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqtgraph, pyside6

I am trying to get *all values* of the object `pg.InfiniteLine()` using [`getXPos()`](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/InfiniteLine.html#InfiniteLine.addMarker:%7E:text=(self)-,def%20getXPos(self)%3A,-return%20self.) method.

I tried the following (this code snippet is set inside of `class MainWindow(QMainWindow)`):

```py
inf = pg.InfiniteLine(movable=True, angle=90, label='x={value:.3f}:{value:.3f}', 
                       labelOpts={'position':0.1, 'color': (200,200,100), 'fill': (200,200,200,50), 'movable': True})
inf.setPos([0,0])
self.graphWidget.addItem(inf)
```

Note: `value` in `label='{value:.3f}:{value:.3f}'` is after converting a list of strings `t_string_list[:5] = ['0:0', '0:1', '0:2', '0:3', '0:4']` (of format H:M) to minutes stored in a variable `t_time_value`.

What I am trying to do is that `label` be set back to `x=H:M` displayed in the graph. To do that, I am trying to get all values of `getXPos()` for me to use [Converting a float to hh:mm format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27496967/10543310).

I tried to do `print(inf.getXPos())` but prints only `0`. I also tried `print(inf.getXPos(t_time_value))` I got `TypeError: getXPos() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. I am not sure how to label the `InfiniteLine` with `x=H:M` where H:M should be values using `label='{value:.3f}:{value:.3f}'.format(*divmod(pos / 60, 1))` argument of `inf` where I am facing difficulties to define `pos`.

This post is continuous to [How to plot hour:min time in ISO 8601 time format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73240127/10543310)

**Note:** `label='{value:.3f}:{value:.3f}'` already gives correct positions whenever I move the line, but I couldn't do like this `label='{value:.3f}:{value:.3f}'.format(value/60, 1)` because `value` isn't defined.

Comment: Your first sentence doesn't make a lot of sense, as you cannot get "all values" of a line. Also, `getXPos()` cannot obviously accept arguments, since it returns the *current* x position. Now, the question is: if you want to convert the value to 'H:M', why are you trying to use `.3f`, which will always get 3 decimal values? Also considering your previous question, it seems to me that you're a bit confused about time specifications and string formatting...

Comment: I used the following: `self.inf.sigPositionChanged.connect(self.x_pos_is_changed)` and `def x_pos_is_changed(self): print(self.inf.getXPos())` now I am able to print all positions whenever I move the line, but I am not sure how to store the values to use them for my case!

Comment: I am trying to go step by step, I believe being able to store the values of `getXPos()` so I can use them in `' '.format()` will allow me to review how to change the time.

Comment: No, you cannot "store the values". This is a floating point based system, there's no way you can get "all possible values", since there are *infinite* values even between 0 and 1.

Comment: I believe there is a way by using Signals and Slots. The data plotted is of fixed-size. I am just trying to use use the values to label the line with more appropriate label using the format `H:M` instead of real `minutes` only. `getXPos()` values are just minutes.

Comment: The fact that the data has fixed size is completely irrelevant: the position is *always* in real values, not integers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247160/discussion-between-joe-and-musicamante).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use evaluation in a basic format string, nor try to "get all values", since graphs use *real* numbers: you can have infinite points between 0 and 1.

The possible solution is to add the `InfLineLabel` manually, using a subclass that overrides the default behavior of `valueChanged`:

```py
class InfTimeLabel(pg.InfLineLabel):
    def valueChanged(self):
        if not self.isVisible():
            return
        value = self.line.value()
        h, m = divmod(value, 60)
        text = '{}:{:06.3f}'.format(int(h), m)
        self.setText(text)
        self.updatePosition()
```

Then add it like this:

```py
    infLine = pg.InfiniteLine(movable=True, angle=90)
    opts = {
        'position': 0.1,
        'color': (200, 200, 100),
        'fill': (200, 200, 200, 50),
        'movable': True
    }
    infLine.label = InfTimeLabel(infLine, **opts)

    self.graphWidget.addItem(infLine)
```